# ORM to create single entity from more than one database tables

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, nhibernate, orm

Well tested running system have already defined entity called 'User'.

Now I need to add a new property to User entity (ex: Age)
To do this in the safe way, I do not like to do any changes with the existing data base table, because that is very risky in my case. I need a way to rebuild the User entity with the minimum code changes.

So my proposal is:

- Create a new table (user_age), with two columns (user_id, age)
- Modify the user entity to add property 'age' and its getter-setters
- So my entity (User) properties, will be saved to two different tables (user and user_age)
- Loading the user is also similarly.

Is this possible to do with hibernate....??

If not, Any other safer way to do this with Hibernate...?

what are the available ORMs that provide this kind of feature (nhibernate, entityframwork,etc... or any other ORM)...?

Comment: Do you mean Hibernate, or do you mean NHibernate?  That is, are you working in .NET, or in Java?

Comment: I am doing a general analysis on ORM, so no need to worry about java or .net

Comment: But you say you already have a "well tested running system".  What language is this system running in?  Are you suggesting that you're willing to throw away all of that good, already-stable code, just to implement this one feature?

Comment: @JanakaPriyadarshana: You should accept answers at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are various approaches:

[1] See JPA Secondary Tables. This allows you to map an Entity to two or more tables.

Section 2.2.7: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2235

[2] Create another Entity, say UserInfo, mapped to this new table. Create a one-to-one mapping from User to UserInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that.
I've used for a similar problem a `joined-subclass`.

**Base**:

```
<class name="User" table="Users">
   <id name="Code" type="System.Guid">
      <column name="Code" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    ...
</class>
```

**Subclass**:

```
<joined-subclass name="UserExt" extends=User" table="UsersExt">
    <key column="Code" />

    <property name="Age">
        <column name="Age" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</joined-subclass>
```

A good reference [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass).

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate's `join` mapping is for exactly this case.

See [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join) and the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join) for more information.  From the documentation:

> Using the `<join>` element, it is possible to map properties of one class to several tables, when there's a 1-to-1 relationship between the tables.

From my searches, it looks like it is also possible to do this with Entity Framework: [Simon J Ince - Mapping two Tables to one Entity in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/23/mapping-two-tables-to-one-entity-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) .  I think this article is about Entity Framework v1, and things could have changed by now, but it appears that there is an important limitation in Entity Framework's version of this mapping:

> ... it requires a record in each table to exist as the generated SQL uses an INNER JOIN. It makes sense if you're using a new model, but I guess this is more tricky if you're mapping to an existing schema and data.

With NHibernate, you can set the `optional` attribute on the `join` mapping to tell it to use outer joins instead of inner joins.

> `optional` (optional - defaults to `false`): If enabled, NHibernate will insert a row only if the properties defined by this join are non-null and will always use an outer join to retrieve the properties.